# Solve shorten notation by regular expression

Tags: r, regex

I want to solve two shorten notation in R.

- For Ade/i, I should get Ade, Adi
- For Do(i)lfal, I should get Dolfal, Doilfal

I have this solution

```
b='Do(i)lferl'
gsub(pattern = '(\\w+)\\((\\w+)+\\)', replacement='\\1\\i,\\1\\2', x=b)
```

Can anyone help me to code this

Comment: `gsub('(\\w*)\\((\\w+)\\)(\\w*)', '\\1\\2\\3,\\1\\3', gsub("(\\w*)(\\w)/(\\w)\\b", "\\1\\2, \\1\\3", b))`? [Demo](https://tio.run/##JYvLCoAgFAX3fYW4ud4SpFy3CPqMs5IsBCEwos83H5vDMMxJObuV9lsFjqdPUWyHN4GG63mdIgV8IwOqwlSAuyEtCJiBBbC6kS2unWRP6rJpCziphewHLXpejGPO@Qc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these values are part of a dataframe, you can do this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Nickname = c("Ade/i", "Do(i)lfal")
)

df$Nickname_new[1] <- paste0(sub("(?=.*/)(.*)/.*", "\\1", df$Nickname[1], perl = T), ",", paste0(unlist(str_split(df$Nickname[1], "\\w/")), collapse = ""))
df$Nickname_new[2] <- paste0(sub("(.*)(\\(.*\\))(.*)", "\\1\\3", df$Nickname[2]),",", sub("(.*)\\((\\w)\\)(.*)", "\\1\\2\\3\\4", df$Nickname[2]))
```

which gives you:

```
df
   Nickname   Nickname_new
1     Ade/i        Ade,Adi
2 Do(i)lfal Dolfal,Doilfal
```

**EDIT**:

Just in case the whole thing is not part of a dataframe but an atomic vector, you can do this:

```
x <- c("Ade/i", "Do(i)lfal")

c(paste0(sub("/.*", "", x[grepl("/", x)]), ", ", sub("./", "", x[grepl("/", x)])), 
  paste0(sub("(.*)\\((\\w)\\)(.*)", "\\1\\2\\3\\4", x[grepl("\\(", x)]), ", ", sub("\\(\\w\\)", "", x[grepl("\\(", x)])))
```

which gives you:

```
[1] "Ade, Adi"       "Doilfal, Dolfal"
```

If there are values that you don't want to change, then this regex by @Wiktor will work (it works even with any scenario!):

```
x <- c("Ade/i", "Do(i)lfal", "Peter", "Mary")
gsub('(\\w*)\\((\\w+)\\)(\\w*)', '\\1\\2\\3, \\1\\3', gsub("(\\w*)(\\w)/(\\w)\\b", "\\1\\2, \\1\\3", x))
```

which gives you:

```
[1] "Ade, Adi"       "Doilfal, Dolfal" "Peter"          "Mary"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, is there any way to write for a single string (not for list and dataframe). Peform both operations if required otherwise leave it as it is